# Inserting personalized text into a js var no= document.getElementById result

Tags: javascript, var

I'm stuck here... I'm doing several questions in different lines with yes/no answers in a drop down menus. When everything is answered I want to click in the "Generate" botton and gather all the questions with th yes/no answers into a single "result" box in just a simple plain paragraph. this is what I have so far (I have no idea of html/js etc. coding but I'm good in googling things). `

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
    Done it?
    <select id="q1">
        <option>Yes</option>
        <option>No</option>
    </select>
    <p>
        Checked Around?
        <select id="q2">
            <option>Yes</option>
            <option>No</option>
        </select>
        <p>
            <input type="button" onclick="myFunction1()" value="Generate">
            <input type="text" id="result" size="25">
</form>
<script>
    function myFunction1() {
        var no = document.getElementById("q1");
        var option = no.options[no.selectedIndex].text;
        var txt = document.getElementById("result").value;
        txt = txt + option;
        document.getElementById("result").value = txt;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note that html markup is eddited on fields sent to the server (mostly to prevent scripting), so check if the text is what you wrotte

Comment: Googling doesn't make you a programmer. You have to learn to code anyway.

Comment: I'm not a programmer, I'm just trying to do some useful things here.. and let me paraphrase my question: How do I gather different answers to questions and condense all together, question + answer, in a result box? Ex. Question: How are you doing? Drop down answers: Fine/Alright, chooses Fine, click in "generate" button, Result in different box: How are you doing? Fine.(Several questions and answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [DEMO](http://codepen.io/presstep/pen/7bcaec6cab3ac36392ecbd94ad154f64/?editors=100)

[image]
Try adding proper labels to your selects, adding a name to your form, and doing something like:

```
<form name="myForm">
  <p>
    <label for="q1">Done it?</label>
    <select id="q1">
      <option>Yes</option>
      <option>No</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="q2">Checking Around?</label>
    <select id="q2">
      <option>Yes</option>
      <option>No</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <input type="button" onclick="populateResults()" value="Generate">
  <div id="result"></div>
</form>
```

then add the submit handler:

```
function populateResults() {
  var selects = document.forms.myForm.querySelectorAll('select'),
      result = document.getElementById("result");
  Array.from(selects).forEach(function(a, i) {
      var answer = a.options[a.selectedIndex].text,
          question = selects[i].labels[0].textContent;
      result.innerHTML += question + ' ' + answer + '<br>';
  })
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, that's exactly what I was trying to accomplish, you got it I appreciate it!!

Comment: np @gapp06gt. anytime.

Answer (score 1):

Your calling `myFunction1()` in the handler to `<input type="button" onclick="myFunction1()" value="Generate">` but `myFunction1()` is defined below your `button` , so it doesn't exist when you assign it. move your `<script>` tag to the top of the file.

By the way there's a logical error here :

`txt = txt + option;` because if the user clicks the  `button` twice it will add previous result to the new value.

Comment: No. `onclick` here is an attribute, i.e. it's a string. The value of it will be evaluated at the time when user really clicks on the button, not at parsing time.

Comment: @Teemu I checked it in jsfiddle , every second click to the button concatenates the previous value with the new value.

Comment: Yes, but your explanation of placing the handler function is wrong, `myFunction1` was defined correctly in OP's case, and is available to the button when user clicks it.

Comment: @Ramanlfc the "Generate" but works but i can't figure out how to combine and gather both answers, question 1 and 2, and put them in a result box below. Ex. Q1? Answer